# Spring Boot - Cannot create session after the response has been committed - JWT Filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm trying to authenticate users with JWT token in Spring Security. I have one class - JWTFilter that extends OncePerRequest interface and implements doFilterInternal method. In that method I have an exception.

Here is the JWTFilter class definition.

```
public class JWTFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Value("${jwt.header}")
    private String header;

    private TokenUtil tokenUtil;

    public JWTFilter(TokenUtil tokenUtil) {
        this.tokenUtil = tokenUtil;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                FilterChain filterChain) throws 
     ServletException, IOException {
        String jwt = resolveToken(httpServletRequest);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && this.tokenUtil.validateToken(jwt)) {
            Authentication authentication = 
            this.tokenUtil.getAuthentication(jwt);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    private String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader(header);
        return (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer "))
        ? bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length())
        : null;
    }
}
```

Everytime when `filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);`
is called it throws the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2983) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2416) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:908) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:920) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:250) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:250) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:250) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.camunda.bpm.webapp.impl.security.auth.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:68) ~[camunda-webapp-7.11.0-classes.jar:7.11.0]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at com.logate.lts.core.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTFilter.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]

Here is my Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint;
private TokenUtil tokenUtil;


@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
{
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
        .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
        .antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
        .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
        .antMatchers("/content/**")
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
        .antMatchers("/test/**")
        .antMatchers("/websocket/**");
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
        // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
        .csrf().disable()

        .headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
        //.headers().cacheControl().disable().and()

        // don't create session
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint).and()

        .authorizeRequests()

        // allow anonymous resource requests on login and reset password
        .antMatchers("/api/user/authenticate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/active-directory/authenticate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/cockpit/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/tasklist/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/engine/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();

        // any other request needs authentication
        //.anyRequest().authenticated();

    // Custom JWT based security filter
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public JWTFilter jwtFilter() {
    return new JWTFilter(tokenUtil);
}

@Autowired
public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder,
                                    CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) throws Exception
{
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Autowired
public void setHttp401UnauthorizedEntryPoint(Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint) {
    this.http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint = http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint;
}

@Autowired
public void setTokenUtil(TokenUtil tokenUtil) {
    this.tokenUtil = tokenUtil;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you pls post your security config. I suspect spring security is trying to establish a session.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf, I have updated a question.

Comment: @HerilMuratovic First of all you are using Token based authentication mechanism, so you don't worry about session management.

Comment: @AlexpandiyanChokkan what you suggest?

Comment: Does anyone knows how to fix this issue?